# How call a function when an item in MemoryCache will expire?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to use `MemoryCache`. I want to set some keys/values in `MemoryCache` .
my values are important and expired at a specified time. for example 120 Seconds.
every 60 seconds my keys/values and expired time are updated(for 120 seconds). if some keys are not updated I want to find out what the key is then I call a function to alert the system admin.
What can I do?

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by using a combination of **MemoryCache** and a background task that periodically checks for expired keys and takes appropriate actions.

**You can get an idea from this code:**

```
using System;
using System.Threading;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Memory;

public class CacheManager
{
    private readonly IMemoryCache _memoryCache;
    private readonly Timer _timer;
    private readonly TimeSpan _expirationTime;
    private readonly TimeSpan _updateInterval;

    public CacheManager(IMemoryCache memoryCache, TimeSpan expirationTime, TimeSpan updateInterval)
    {
        _memoryCache = memoryCache;
        _expirationTime = expirationTime;
        _updateInterval = updateInterval;
        
        // Set up a timer to periodically update the cache
        _timer = new Timer(UpdateCache, null, TimeSpan.Zero, _updateInterval);
    }

    public void Set(string key, object value)
    {
        _memoryCache.Set(key, value, _expirationTime);
    }

    private void UpdateCache(object state)
    {
        // Iterate through cache entries and check if any have expired
        foreach (var cacheEntry in _memoryCache)
        {
            if (cacheEntry.Value == null)
            {
                // Handle expired key
                AlertAdmin(cacheEntry.Key);
                // Remove expired key from cache
                _memoryCache.Remove(cacheEntry.Key);
            }
        }
    }

    private void AlertAdmin(string key)
    {
        // Implement logic to alert system admin about expired key
        Console.WriteLine($"Key '{key}' has expired and was not updated.");
    }
}
```

- The **CacheManager** class manages the **MemoryCache** and includes a timer (**_timer**) that periodically checks for expired keys and updates them.
- When you set a value using the **Set** method, it sets the key-value pair in the **MemoryCache** with the specified expiration time.
- The **UpdateCache** method is called periodically by the timer. It iterates through all cache entries, checks if any have expired, alerts the system admin about expired keys, and removes them from the cache.
- You can create an instance of **CacheManager** and use its **Set** method to set keys and values in the cache. The cache entries will be automatically updated and expired keys will be handled according to your logic in the **AlertAdmin** method.

You can adjust the expiration time and update interval according to your requirements. Additionally, you may need to handle concurrency and synchronization if multiple threads are accessing the cache concurrently.

Answer (score 0):

I think you Can register a PostEvictionCallback  to tackle your use case : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.caching.memory.cacheentryextensions.registerpostevictioncallback?view=dotnet-plat-ext-8.0

There is example in Microsoft Doc:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/performance/caching/memory?view=aspnetcore-8.0#memorycacheentryoptions

Comment: Please avoid giving link-only answers. Can you add more context to your answer? People should be able to understand the answer without leaving the site.